# i have no of elements if clicking div count will increase. at the same time click other div, first div count will be 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, web-frontend

You can store [data][1] with each element counting the number of times each was clicked.

```js
$('.container').click(function() {
  if ($(this).data('count')) { // already been clicked
    $(this).data('count', $(this).data('count') + 1); // add one
  } else { // first click
    $(this).data('count', 1); // initialize the count
  }
  $(this).html($(this).data('count')); // show it
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">container</div>
<div class="container">container</div>
<div class="container">container</div>
<div class="container">container</div>
<div class="container">container</div>
<div class="container">container</div>
```

Comment: looks like the demo works. Is this a demo or question?

Comment: here first  container click function count increase like 1,2,3,4 and next  second container  click that time first container count i want 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Just set other data to 0 on second click

```js
$('.container').click(function() {

  if ($(this).data('count')) { // already been clicked
    
    $(this).data('count', $(this).data('count') + 1); // add one
  } else { // first click
    $('.container').not(this).data('count', 0);
    $(this).data('count', 1); // initialize the count
  }
  $('.container').each(function(i, v) {
    $(v).html($(v).data('count')); // show it
  })



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">container</div>
<div class="container">container</div>
<div class="container">container</div>
<div class="container">container</div>
<div class="container">container</div>
<div class="container">container</div>
```